# how to layout support for various screen in android?

Tags: android

[image]

[image]

i am developing gallery view using gridview,in small screen my layout design fixed very well,but large screen did not my design,In large screen have some spaces bellow "load more picture" button refer fig2,how can i solve this problem,my Manifest file added this lines for support various screen,please give some sample code for me..

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
 android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"
 android:anyDensity="false" />
```

and my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="340dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"  
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="335dp" android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:background="@color/black">


 <GridView 
                    android:id="@+id/jr_lookbook_grid" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="335dp" android:numColumns="4"
                    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:columnWidth="90dp" android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape"  
                    android:gravity="center"  android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout0209_img"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="311dp">
         <Button  android:id="@+id/click"
                android:background="#AA000000" 
                   android:text="Load More Pictures..."
                  android:textColor="@color/white"                  
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="30dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02_img"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/black"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"> 
   <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"         
        android:scrollbars="none" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true">
</ImageView>  
    </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"     android:background="#AA000000" 
         android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/back
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@drawable/back1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" /
                 <Button
                  android:background="@drawable/forward5"
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"/>
                  <Button
                  android:background="@drawable/menushare"
                android:id="@+id/photoshare"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" />
</LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

Thanks All

Answer (score 3):

You have to write xml code for large screen.  I think you are keeping your xml file in res/layout folder.  if it is you can keep three folders to differentiate various screens like res/layout-small, res/layout, res/layout-long.  In these three folders you can set different alignements to various screen types.  For Medium Screen, keep your xml code in layout, and for small screens - keep it in layout-small and etc.,  and set

```
    <supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"        
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

these lines in your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

You may also wish to add

```
android:xlargeScreens="true"
```

as per: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-mode-for-apps-on-large-screens.html

So your screens element would look like:

```
<supports-screens 
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
```